# Solving this differential equation to get y(t)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation.

$ay - b = \sqrt{(1+y'^2)}$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants. How do I solve this to get $y(t)$? I am totally stuck at this point. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(ay-b)^2=1+y'^2 \\
y'= \sqrt{(ay-b)^2-1}$$
$z=ay-b$ leads to 
$$\frac{z'}{\sqrt{z^2-1}}=a$$
which is easy to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange (basic algebra),

$\frac {dy}{dt} = \pm \sqrt{(ay-b)^2-1}$

This is separable. Hint:$ay-b = \cosh u$ as a substitution.

Comment: Thank you. I also got something similar right before I checked your reply. I am relieved to be on the right track.